# Simulating a custom reporter block in Scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch

In Scratch 2.0, support for custom stack blocks ([procedures](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Procedure)) was added. But is there any way to use this to "abstract away" logic that returns a value?

For example, i have here a script to naively calculate exponents: ([view graphic representation](http://blob8108.github.io/scratchblocks2/#set%20%5Bbase%20v%5D%20to%20%5B2%5D%0Aset%20%5Bindex%20v%5D%20to%20%5B3%5D%0A...%20%2F%2F%20above%20is%20for%20initializing%0Aset%20%5Bresult%20v%5D%20to%20(base)%0Arepeat%20until%20%3C(index)%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%3E%0A%20%20set%20%5Bresult%20v%5D%20to%20((result)%20*%20(base))%0A%20%20change%20%5Bindex%20v%5D%20by%20(-1)))

```
set [base v] to [2]
set [index v] to [3]
... // above is for initializing
set [result v] to (base)
repeat until <(index) = [1]>
  set [result v] to ((result) * (base))
  change [index v] by (-1)
```

How could i export this logic to a "custom reporter" to reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by creating a custom command block, and storing the return value in a variable. This has some drawbacks, such as not allowing recursive calls, but works in most cases. I also recommend setting the block to run without screen refresh.

Simply define it like this, with the return value available as `result`:

```
define (base) ^ (exp)
set [index v] to (exp) // need a variable, as arguments are immutable
set [result v] to (base)
repeat until <(index) = [1]>
  set [result v] to ((result) * (base))
  change [index v] by (-1)
```

It can then be called like:

```
when gf clicked
(4) ^ (3) // the stack block
say (join [4 ^ 3 = ] (result)) // result is set by the [()^()] block
```

[See this in rendered ScratchBlocks.](http://blob8108.github.io/scratchblocks2/#define%20(base)%20%5E%20(exp)%0Aset%20%5Bindex%20v%5D%20to%20(exp)%20%2F%2F%20need%20a%20variable%2C%20as%20arguments%20are%20immutable%0Aset%20%5Bresult%20v%5D%20to%20(base)%0Arepeat%20until%20%3C(index)%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%3E%0A%20%20set%20%5Bresult%20v%5D%20to%20((result)%20*%20(base))%0A%20%20change%20%5Bindex%20v%5D%20by%20(-1)%0A%0Awhen%20gf%20clicked%0A(4)%20%5E%20(3)%20%2F%2F%20the%20stack%20block%0Asay%20(join%20%5B4%20%5E%203%20%3D%20%5D%20(result))%20%2F%2F%20result%20is%20set%20by%20the%20%5B()%5E()%5D%20block)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example ([rendered](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#define%20split%20%5Btext%5D%20by%20%5Bsplitter%5D%0Adelete%20(all%20v)%20of%20%5Boutput%20list%20v%5D%0Aset%20%5Bparse%20v%5D%20to%20%5B0%5D%0Aset%20%5Bcur%20string%20v%5D%20to%20%5B%5D%0Arepeat%20until%20((parse)%20%3E%20(length%20of%20(splitter))%0A%09if%20%3C(letter%20(parse)%20of%20(text))%20%3D%20(splitter)%3E%20then%0A%09%09add%20(cur%20string)%20to%20%5Boutput%20list%20v%5D%0A%09%09set%20%5Bcur%20string%20v%5D%20to%20%5B%5D%0A%09else%0A%09%09set%20%5Bcur%20string%20v%5D%20to%20(join%20(cur%20string)%20(letter%20(parse)%20of%20(text)))%0A%09end%0Aend%0A%0Awhen%20GF%20clicked%0Asplit%20%5BHello%2C%20world!%20Do%20you%20like%20this%3F%5D%20by%20%5B%20%5D%20%2F%2F%20That's%20a%20space.%0A%0A%2F%2F%20That%20should%20output%20a%20list%3A%20%5B%22Hello%2C%22%2C%20%22world!%22%2C%20%22Do%22%2C%20%22you%22%2C%20%22like%22%2C%20%22this%3F%22%5D%0A%0Adefine%20the%20answer%20to%20life%0Aset%20%5Boutput%20var%20v%5D%20to%20(42)%0A%0Awhen%20GF%20clicked%0Athe%20answer%20to%20life%0Asay%20(output%20var))):

```
define split [text] by [splitter]
delete (all v) of [output list v]
set [parse v] to [0]
set [cur string v] to []
repeat until ((parse) > (length of (splitter))
   if <(letter (parse) of (text)) = (splitter)> then
      add (cur string) to [output list v]
      set [cur string v] to []
   else
      set [cur string v] to (join (cur string) (letter (parse) of (text)))
   end
end

when GF clicked
split [Hello, world! Do you like this?] by [ ] // That's a space.

// That should output a list: ["Hello,", "world!", "Do", "you", "like", "this?"]

define the answer to life
set [output var v] to (42)

when GF clicked
the answer to life
say (output var)
```

It shows off how to use both a list output and a variable output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a second, more complicated way to do this. It allows for recursive blocks, and you can run a block multiple times. I call it the stacking method, because i use a list as a stack. For an example, see [this project that i made](http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/22744166/).

This method also doesn't clutter up the variables palette.

```
define (base) ^ (index) recursive
if <(index) = [1]>
  add (base) to [stack v]
else
  (base) ^ ((index) - (1)) recursive // adds the previous item to the stack
  add ((base) * (item (last v) of [stack v])) to [stack v]
  delete ((length of [stack v]) - (1)) of [stack v] // clean up
```

It can then be accessed using essentially the same method as i explained in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948250/3187556):

```
when gf clicked
(4) ^ (3) recursive // the stack block
say (join [4 ^ 3 = ] (item (last v) of [stack v])) // get the item from the end of the stack
delete [last v] of [stack v] // optional, if you want to clean up
```

[See this in rendered ScratchBlocks.](http://blob8108.github.io/scratchblocks2/#define%20(base)%20%5E%20(index)%20recursive%0Aif%20%3C(index)%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%3E%0A%20%20add%20(base)%20to%20%5Bstack%20v%5D%0Aelse%0A%20%20(base)%20%5E%20((index)%20-%20(1))%20recursive%20%2F%2F%20adds%20the%20previous%20item%20to%20the%20stack%0A%20%20add%20((base)%20*%20(item%20(last%20v)%20of%20%5Bstack%20v%5D))%20to%20%5Bstack%20v%5D%0A%20%20delete%20((length%20of%20%5Bstack%20v%5D)%20-%20(1))%20of%20%5Bstack%20v%5D%20%2F%2F%20clean%20up%0A%20%20%0A%0Awhen%20gf%20clicked%0A(4)%20%5E%20(3)%20recursive%20%2F%2F%20the%20stack%20block%0Asay%20(join%20%5B4%20%5E%203%20%3D%20%5D%20(item%20(last%20v)%20of%20%5Bstack%20v%5D))%20%2F%2F%20get%20the%20item%20from%20the%20end%20of%20the%20stack%0Adelete%20%5Blast%20v%5D%20of%20%5Bstack%20v%5D%20%2F%2F%20optional%2C%20if%20you%20want%20to%20clean%20up)