# ORD and CHAR in Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

I am coming across more and more situations in Scratch where I have to convert a number to its ACSII character  or visa versa. There is no built function in the blocks for this.

My solution is to create a list of size 26 and append letters A-Z into each sequence using a variable called alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and  iterating over it with a Repeat block and appending LETTER COUNT of ALPHABET to the list.The result is a list data structure with letters A_Z between location 1 to 26.In effect creating my own ASCII table.

To do a converson say from number 26 to 'Z' I have to iterate over the list to get the correct CHAR value. It really slows down the program that is heavily dependent on the CHR() feature. Is there a better or more efficient solution?

Comment: Is the part you're having trouble with getting the letter from a number or vice versa?

Comment: both ways as o ne function is the inverse of the other both situations often crop up when writing string manipulation programs. I make some cypher programs for example.

Answer (score 1):

> My solution is to create a list of size 26 and append letters A-Z into each sequence using a variable called alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Stop right there. You don't even need to convert it into a list. You can just look it up directly from the string.

To get a character from an index is very easy. Just use the `(letter () of [])` block.

To get the index of a character is more complex. Unfortunately, Scratch doesn't have a built-in way to do that. What i would do here is define a `index of [] in []` [custom pseudo-reporter block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948250/3187556):

```
define index of (char) in (str)
set [i v] to [1]
repeat until <<(i) = (length of (str))> or <(letter (i) of (str)) = (char)>>
    change [i v] by (1)
```

<sub>[view online](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#define%20index%20of%20(char)%20in%20(str)%0Aset%20%5Bi%20v%5D%20to%20%5B1%5D%0Arepeat%20until%20%3C%3C(i)%20%3D%20(length%20of%20(str))%3E%20or%20%3C(letter%20(i)%20of%20(str))%20%3D%20(char)%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20change%20%5Bi%20v%5D%20by%20(1)%0Aend%0Aif%20%3C%3C(i)%20%3D%20(length%20of%20(str))%3E%20and%20%3Cnot%20%3C(letter%20(i)%20of%20(str))%20%3D%20(char)%3E%3E%3E%0A%09set%20%5Bi%20v%5D%20to%20%5B0%5D)</sub>

You can then call the block as `index of [a] in (alphabet)` and it will set the `i` variable to 1.

This code doesn't have any case for if the character isn't found, but the link i provided does include that, if you need.

Comment: Yes I agree with the first solution and usually use that method in Python. Your second solution using the reporter block seems to iterate N times in the worst case so doesn't actually solve the second problem. Perhaps, that is what ord() does but I suspect it uses a lookup in constant time due to the ascii character set  being built in electronically in a chip set? The difference in running time on encryption programs is enormous when using scratch and Python.

Comment: I agree it's unfortunate, but that's how you have to do it in Scratch.

Comment: What about binary search?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Snap!](http://snap.berkeley.edu/) which is similar to Scratch, but has more blocks. Snap! has a unicode block, that will convert a character to its ASCII or unicode value.

Comment: Yes, Snap has built-in functions for converting a character to ASCII value and back: `unicode of []` and `unicode () as letter`. Unicode and ASCII codes are the same for characters that have an ASCII code.